# Nested negative if statements with assignments in condition

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I have the following piece of code:

```
if (!$x = some_function(1)) {
    if (!$x = some_function(2)) {
        return something;
    }
}
```

I want to know which of the following statements are equivalent:

A.

```
if (some_function(1)) {
    $x = some_function(1));
}
else if (some_function(2)) {
    $x = some_function(2));
}
else {
    return something;
}
```

Or if it's essentially saying that it should be overridden, like so:

B.

```
if (some_function(1)) {
    $x = some_function(1));
}
if (some_function(2)) {
    $x = some_function(2));
}
if (!$x) {
    return something;
}
```

Another way of wording the question: in an assignment within an `if` statement, is the variable evaluated for `false` first, and then assigned if `false`, or does the assignment happen first, and then the variable evaluated next?

Comment: The assignment to $x is first, then the condition test after.

Comment: Also, that assignment remains in scope, so it's very easy to inadvertently leak variables around the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement is not equivalent to any of the others. It would be equivalent to this:

```
$x = some_function(1); // assign $x first
if(!$x){ // check if $x is falsy
  $x = some_function(2); // overwrite $x (not the function itself)
  if(!$x){ // check if $x is still falsy
   // do stuff
  }
}
```

Or, if the variable is not important, this is also equivalent

```
if(!some_function(1) && !some_function(2)){...}
```

the only difference is the first one always provides a value to `$x`, which is probably used somewhere else.

This is also the same, using ternary

```
$x = some_function(1) ? some_function(1) : some_function(2);
if(!$x) // do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Scuzzy for the clarification -- it seems like the proper equivalent is this:

```
if (some_function(1)) {
    $x = some_function(1));
}
if (!$x && some_function(2)) {
    $x = some_function(2));
}
if (!$x) {
    return something;
}
```